# Spearman's rho vs Cox regression

Tags: cox-model

I'm searching the predictors associated survival among 12 children with a disease named hemophagoctic syndrome treated only specific treatment.Our statisician used spearman's rho test but the journal commented this method as'' Cox-regression analysis should be considered to study predictors associated with survival'' .I do not understand why our statistician used spearman's rho test than the cox regression analysis. Help please.

Comment: If you want to understand why someone did something, you'd be best placed to ask them.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what your statistician thought, but you could ask her/him.

Spearmans's correlation is a bivariate technique, while Cox regression is multivariate technique. There are a couple of other advantages with Cox regression when dealing with "time till event kind of data". Whether those advantages apply or are relevant to your case depends on the details of your study. If your statistician is used to work with medical studies, then (s)he should also be very familiar with Cox regression.